# Method of undetermined coefficients and taylor expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to figure out how to expand the functions. What would the taylor expansion of f(x-2h), f(x-h), f(x), f(x+h), and f(x+2h) look like? After this, I believe that I just need to combine the like terms and make the coefficients of every term except f'(x) equal zero, and make the coefficient of f'(x) equal 1)
[image: underdetermined is a typo, it should be undetermined]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to write around $h=0$
$$f(x+k h)=f(x)+h k f'(x)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 k^2 f''(x)+\frac{1}{6} h^3 k^3
   f^{(3)}(x)+\frac{1}{24} h^4 k^4 f^{(4)}(x)+\frac{1}{120} h^5 k^5
   f^{(5)}(x)+O\left(h^6\right)$$ Gourping, we have
$$f'(x)=f(x) (a+b+c+d+e)+h f'(x) (-2 a-b+d+2 e)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 f''(x) (4 a+b+d+4
   e)+\frac{1}{6} h^3 f^{(3)}(x) (-8 a-b+d+8 e)+\frac{1}{24} h^4 f^{(4)}(x) (16
   a+b+d+16 e)+\frac{1}{120} h^5 f^{(5)}(x) (-32 a-b+d+32 e)+O\left(h^6\right)$$ So, we have
$$a+b+c+d+e=0$$ $$-2 a-b+d+2 e=1$$ $$4 a+b+d+4
   e=0$$ $$-8 a-b+d+8 e=0$$ $$16   a+b+d+16 e=0$$ which give
$$a=\frac 1{12} \quad b=-\frac 23 \quad c=0 \quad d=\frac 23\quad e=-\frac 1{12}$$ which makes
$$a f(x-2h)+b f(x-h)+c f(x)+d f(x+h)+e f(x+2h)=h f'(x)-\frac{1}{30} h^5 f^{(5)}(x)+O\left(h^6\right)$$ and then
$$f'(x)=\frac 1h \Big(\frac 1{12} f(x-2h)-\frac 23 f(x-h)+\frac 23 f(x+h)-\frac 1{12} f(x+2h)\Big)+\frac{1}{30} h^4 f^{(5)}(x)$$

Trying for $f(x)=e^{\pi x}$ at $x=2$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 h & \text{estimate} \\
 0.1 & 1681.74395932 \\
 0.01 & 1682.29659643 \\
 0.001 & 1682.29665105 \\
 0.0001 & 1682.29665106 \\
 0.00001 & 1682.29665106
\end{array}
\right)$$ while the exact value is $1682.29665106$.